# AWS API Gateway api returns request headers failed error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am calling API using react.js application. I am getting error from AWS API Gateway about CORS policy:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://awsapigatewayid.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/staging/top10' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

From React App code for call api like:

```
let options = {
    url: `https://awsapigatewayid.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/staging/top10`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Req-Time': getCurrentTimestamp(),
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    data: data || {},
  };
  if (isAuthorised) {
    options.headers['X-Auth-Token'] = 'usertokengoeshere';
  }
  const response = await axios(options);
```

My API from AWS API Gateway:

[image]

Comment: That is not an API Gateway error, that is your browser blocking the request. Why do you put a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the request? See e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html for further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`, from your API call,  to solve your error, instead add it to your Lambda response. Preferably not with `'*'` but with your actual Origin.